# Concatenate date and time fields and turn into datetime postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table with the date and time fields separated

Table1

```
data           hora            id
2015-01-01    11:40:06          1 
2015-01-01    15:40:06          2
2015-01-02    15:40:06          3 
2015-01-05    10:40:06          4 
2015-01-05    15:40:06          5
2015-01-06    08:23:00          6
```

Now I need to consult the id between 2015-01-01 12:00:00 12:00:00  and 2015-01-05 12:00:00, , should return the ids 2,3,4.
I'm trying to convert and concatenate the date and time fields that are separated in a single datetime field in order to use the 'between' but I can not hit the syntax can someone give an example?

Comment: Just to make sure: those columns are defined as `date` and `time`?

Comment: Use the add `+` operator for that, not the usual concatenation operator (`||`) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Yes are defined date and time.

Comment: Why don't you just store them as `timestamp` in the first place?

Comment: Hello Craig, unfortunately the database is already well and I can not change it. :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It works!

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    (dataemissao + hora) BETWEEN (date '2015-01-21' + time '14:00') 
     AND  (date '2015-01-21' + time '18:00')
```